# textview separated in each row of listview

Tags: android

I have 7 textview which represents a date ex. August 1,August 2,August 3...this 7 textview is showed up in each row of a listview,the problem is when i click the button all textview was showed in the last item of listview.

this is what im trying to achieve
http://img818.imageshack.us/img818/416/q39d.png

listitem0

August 1

listitem1

August 2

....

here is my code in getview

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    //august1
    Calendar mCalendar = new GregorianCalendar();
    mCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.MONDAY);
    SimpleDateFormat mDF = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM");
    String fDate = mDF.format(mCalendar.getTime());
    //august2
    mCalendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
    String secDate = mDF.format(mCalendar.getTime());

    mCalendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
    String tDate = mDF.format(mCalendar.getTime());

    mCalendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
    String fourthDate = mDF.format(mCalendar.getTime());

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, parent, false);
    fDay = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.fDate);
    secDay = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.secDate);
    tDay = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.tDate);
    fourthDay = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.fourthDate);



    Button test = (Button) rowView.findViewById(R.id.btn);

    test.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        //to increment the date
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            weekNumber = weekNumber + 1;
            fDay.setText(getNextWeek(weekNumber));

        }

    });

    fDay.setText(values[position]);
    //text.setText(values[position]);

    // Change icon based on name
    String s = values[position];
    //String bs = values[position];

    System.out.println(s);
//System.out.println(bs);
     //represent date in a row
    //listitem0
    if (s.equals("Date 1")) {
        fDay.setText(fDate);
    //listitem1
    } else if (s.equals("Date 2")) {
    secDay.setText(secDate);
    //listitem2
    } else if (s.equals("Date 3")) {
    tDay.setText(tDate);

    } else if (s.equals("Date 4")) {
        fourthDay.setText(fourthDate);

     ......


    } else {

        // textView.setText(fDate);
    }

    return rowView;
}

// method to adjust the date
private static String getNextWeek(int weekFromToday) {
    Calendar mCalendar = new GregorianCalendar();
    mCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.MONDAY);
    mCalendar.set(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR,
            mCalendar.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR) + weekFromToday);

    SimpleDateFormat mDF = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM");
    String fDate = mDF.format(mCalendar.getTime());
    fDay.setText(fDate);

    mCalendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
    String secDate = mDF.format(mCalendar.getTime());
    mCalendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
    String tDate = mDF.format(mCalendar.getTime());
    mCalendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
    String fourthDate = mDF.format(mCalendar.getTime());

    fDay.setText(fDate);
    secDay.setText(secDate);
    tDay.setText(tDate);
    fourthDay.setText(fourthDate);

    return fDate;

}
```

}

Comment: Couldn't get you. Post question with before and after screen shots.

Comment: Can you explain what you actually want to do?

Comment: i updated my post, i also link the image to make it clear to you guys,tnx

Answer (score 0):

That is a more accurate way to implement `getView` method reusing of list views:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
  View view = null;
  if (convertView == null) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
    view = inflater.inflate(textViewResourceId, parent, false);

  } else {
    view = convertView;
  }

  return view;
}
```

Comment: tried it but but all the textview was inside in one listitem,i want is something like this http://img818.imageshack.us/img818/416/q39d.png

Comment: @user1673416 can you post a screenshot of how it looks like in your case right now?

Comment: ,this is what happening when i press the button http://img22.imageshack.us/img22/2208/i54m.png